# data array does not change

Tags: php, laravel

It is an array with 3 objects. Each object is a group with multiple products and values. Some products are repeated in these groups. I turned it into an array to see if it solved a problem.
The problem is that I change the value of a product in one of these groups and if that product is in another group, even if it is not changed in that group, it ends up receiving the same values ​​as the product that was changed in the other group.
But when transforming into an array, nothing is changed...

```
$array = GroupProduct::where('status', 1);
    $array = $array->with(['groupProductProduct.product' => function($query) use ($id) {
      $query->where('products.situation', 1)->with(['items.orderitems' => function($query2) use ($id) {
        $query2->where([['order_items.order_id', $id]])->with('subitems');
      }]);
    }]);
    $array = $array->get()->toArray();

    $groups = $array;

    foreach ($groups as $key => $groupProduct) {
        foreach ($groupProduct['group_product_product'] as $key2 => $groupProductProduct) {
          if(isset($groupProductProduct['product'])){
            foreach ($groupProductProduct['product']['items'] as $key3 => $productItems) {
              $orderItems = $productItems['orderitems'];
              
              if(isset($productItems['orderitems'])){
                foreach ($productItems['orderitems']['subitems'] as $key4 => $subItem) {
                  
                  if($orderItems['group_product_id'] === $groupProduct['id'] && $subItem['product_item_id'] === $productItems['id']){             
                    $productItems['subitems'] = $subItem;
                    $productItems['unit_value'] = $subItem['unit_value'];
                    $productItems['total_value'] = $subItem['total_value'];
                    $productItems['qtdfnc'] = $subItem['unit_value'] / $groupProductProduct['product']['factor'];
                  }
                  
                }
              }
              
              unset($productItems['orderitems']);      
            }
    
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The default PHP behavior is by value, so in your `for` loop you're actually iterating through a copy. If you want to write to the original you need to pass by reference i.e `&$groupProduct`

Comment: Like this? I'm doing it like this